# getting buffer from a url with http.get

Tags: node.js

i am traying to improve a bit my code so here I am.

I am getting some urls that when i click on this they give me a pdf.
Actually my code is working following this steps

1.- Get all url that i Need (array of urls)

2.- Using promiseAll calling another function that use the http.get(url) for get the BUFFER of the pdf

3.- uploading into Aws S3

My question is, exist or you know another better way of do this?

```
 const BuffersPdfs = await Promise.all(urlPdf.map(async url => await this.getBufferOfPDF(url)))
```

that line gives me an array of Buffers

the function that does the work is this

```
 private static async getBufferOfPDF(url: string) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const req = http.get(url, (res) => {
                if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {
                    return reject(new Error('statusCode=' + res.statusCode));
                }
                const chunkData = []
                res.on('data', chunk => {
                    chunkData.push(chunk);
                }).on('end', () => {
                    const buffer = Buffer.concat(chunkData);
                    resolve(buffer)
                });
            });
            req.on('error', e => {
                console.error("Error:", e)
                reject(e.message);
            });
            req.end();
        });
    }
```

As you can see if my urlPdf Array have 10 urls, it will call 10 times the function of "getBufferOfPDF"...
Any ideas for improve this?

ps: When I have my array of buffers I am using a library called merge PDF that takes all this buffers and join them in one for create a MERGED pdf

Thank you very much.

---

---

Like the example that I gave is that if I have 10 urls YES I need to make 10 http Calls, one way to improve this that I was thinking is that IF exist one property or method on http.get that receive an array of urls and that way I dont need to do a promise All and just need to pass the array of urls for get lowered time

Comment: Thank u and sorry. I Added some info

Comment: @KJ Well i dont understand all that u said but in short words. I am generating dispatch guides of some shipments, so some shipments could have 1 and other many. I need to save the mergedPDF of all the guides of the shipment for eventually use this pdf merged on and endpoint for my frontEnd. The library i am using is this https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-merger-js.
For using this i am creating a temporary variable of buffer using http.get with the url of this pdfs and then using the pdf Merger for after all this upload the buffer to s3